# Passing an Expression as a parameter of a filter function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, linq, typescript

Consider the following Typescript function:

```
getPeople(): Person[] {
    return model.people;
}
```

I'd like to implement it with an embedded filter, which will work based on an Expression that I want to pass as a parameter, more or less like this:

```
getPeopleBy(expression): Person[] {
    return model.people.filter(expression);
}

var filteredPeople = getPeopleBy(p => p.age < 30);
```

With Linq and C#, I can do it by accepting a parameter with this syntaxis `Expression<Func<EcommerceProduct, bool>> filter`

Is there anything similar in Typescript / Javascript?

Comment: Why do you need an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` instead of `Func<T,bool>`?

Comment: I don't want to pass a function as parameter. I want to pass the expression for the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disregard (initial answer - leaving it here so people understand the evolution process):**

Yes, in C# you can do this, but you have to remember TypeScript comes with some sugar syntax that borrows from C#, JavaScript is it's own animal.

In order to pass an expression, you need to remember that a lamba expression is just a function, so in JS you just have, keys, values (objects) and functions (simple, right?).

So to achieve what you want your code should look like this:

```
getPeopleBy(expression: Function): Person[] {
    return model.people.filter(expression);
}

var filteredPeople = getPeopleBy((p: Person) => { return p.age < 30 });
```

PS: may I also recommend you change the function name to **getPeopleWith**?

as you can see, from a human perspective, it makes much more sense to read:

```
getPeopleWith((p: Person) => { return p.age < 30 });
```

Basically it's get the people with the age less than 30, easily readable by any person :)

**Update:**

This will offer you the desired result!

[TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20People%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20people%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20where(expression%3A%20(value%3A%20any%2C%20index%3F%3A%20number%2C%20Array%3F%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20boolean)%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.people.filter(expression)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0APeople.where(p%20%3D%3E%20p.age%20%3C%2030)%3B)

```
class People {
    private static people: any[] = [];

    static where(expression: (value: any, index?: number, Array?: any[]) => boolean): 
                                                                            any[] {
        return this.people.filter(expression);
    }
}


People.where(p => p.age < 30);
```

**Update 2:**

[TypeScript Playground Example using interface definition for callback](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFilter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20index%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Array%3F%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20People%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20people%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20where(expression%3A%20(IFilter)%20%3D%3E%20boolean)%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.people.filter(expression)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0APeople.where(p%20%3D%3E%20p.age%20%3C%2030)%3B)

If you need to write a FluentAPI or something bigger and you're tired of dragging along the callbackfn definition, you can also do something like this:

```
interface IFilter {
    value: any;
    index?: number;
    Array?: any[];
}

class People {
    private static people: any[];

    static where(expression: (IFilter) => boolean): any[] {
        return this.people.filter(expression);
    }
}


People.where(p => p.age < 30);
```

**Update 3:**

[TypeScript Playground with Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IFilter%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20index%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Array%3F%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20People%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20people%3A%20Person%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20where(expression%3A%20(IFilter%3A%20Person)%20%3D%3E%20boolean)%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.people.filter(expression)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0APeople.where(p%20%3D%3E%20p.age%20%3C%2030)%3B)

And with this you can also get nice IntelliSense, by using templates in the interface :)

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
}

interface IFilter<T> {
    value: T;
    index?: number;
    Array?: T[];
}

class People {
    private static people: Person[];

    static where(expression: (IFilter: Person) => boolean): any[] {
        return this.people.filter(expression);
    }
}

People.where(p => p.age < 30);
```

I hope these series of updates help you achieve your goals.

Comment: I see, basically the answer is I can't do it...  Because if this is the solution, I'd much rather exclude the filter from the method and just do: `getPeople().filter(x => x.age > 30)`

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Check out linq.js, you can find more info [here](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/).

With it you can pass a function as parameter to be used as filter.

Googling around I found out there is also a TS library (as I see you are using TypeScript), you can find it [here](https://github.com/kutyel/linq.ts). I have not tested it anyway :)

Comment: I'll have a look, but it seems that Vlad's answer works with no additional library